# How to push location with GeoFire/FireBase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

How can I set up a unique ID or push when I do:

```
 geoFire.setLocation("item", myLocation);
```

Right now, if I set a location as User A and then later set a location as User B, the set location will be replaced by User B.

Comment: If you want to keep separate items for User A and User B, then you need to ensure that the items have separate keys. For example, you could base the key on the user's ID: `geoFire.setLocation("User_A_item", myLocation); geoFire.setLocation("User_B_item", otherLocation);`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh, that worked! Thank you.